# cloudwatch Alarm actions with multiple SNS topics usind cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

HI im using below Resource using cloudformation

```
"SNSTopic1":{
            "Default":"<prodteamarn>",
            "Description":"ProdteamSNStopic",
            "Type":"String"
            },

"SNSTopic2":{
            "Default":<featureteanarn>,
            "Description":"featureteamSNStopic",
            "Type":"String"
            },

    "Resources":{
            "SpilloverCountAlarm":{
                "Properties":{
                    "AlarmActions":[
                        {
                            "Ref":"SNSTopic1"
                        },
                       {
                         "Ref":"SNSTopic2"  //can i use multiple SNS topics             
                       }
                    ],
                    "AlarmDescription":"Spillover is Too Large",
                    "ComparisonOperator":"GreaterThanThreshold",
                    "Dimensions":[
                        {
                            "Name":"LoadBalancerName",
                            "Value":{
                                "Ref":"xyz"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "EvaluationPeriods":"2",
                    "MetricName":"SpilloverCount",
                    "Namespace":"AWS/ELB",
                    "Period":"100",
                    "Statistic":"Sum",
                    "Threshold":"3"
                },
                "Type":"AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm"
            }
```

So the question is can i use multiple SNS topics in Alarmactions??? as i need to send notifications to both prod and feature teams as they have different Arn for SNS topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, according to the [CloudFormation documentation for Alarm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html#cfn-cloudwatch-alarms-alarmaction), the property AlarmActions is a List of actions to be performed. This means you should be able to notify multiple SNS Topics without issue.

You can verify this by looking at the [AWS Console UI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/ConsoleAlarms.html) for setting up an Alarm. The section for Actions is also a List that allows for the configuration of multiple actions to be configured.